# What does "^Cn" do with setsid?

Tags: bash

In a product documentation I see the command:

```
setsid ^Cn spring-boot:run -o >> java_app.log
```

It does not work for me but the error is not very clear. My question is what could the `^Cn` be doing in the command? I have searched a lot but could not find a proper result.

Comment: @FilipeBrandenburger wow! Thank you. After reading your comment, it looks like that is exactly what happened with whoever created the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @muru commented, there are references to a `mvn spring-boot:run` command (asking Google about that second part), so that's probably what that's meant to be.

What might have happened is that the writers of the doumentation got to that command through history, had the cursor on the "m" for `mvn` then pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to cancel the command. The shell will then print a `^C` (to indicate that the keystroke was received and the command was cancelled) which would then overwrite the "mv" in `mvn`... Leaving you with one single non-sense `^Cn`.